# Password recovery and password derived key encryption

Tags: security, encryption, web-applications, pbkdf2, password-recovery

Hi (sorry about the wordy post)

I'm working on a web app that will store some of the users personal data.
I have looked into various ways of encrypting the data to protect it from intruders if the database or web server was compromised and think that creating and storing a unique “master key” encrypted with a password derived key for each user is the best way to go for my set-up.

The only issue I can see is with forgotten passwords. Currently, the users can reset a forgotten password by receiving an email containing a link with a unique token that takes then to the password reset form.

My idea is to add security questions to the registration page that will be used to create a 2nd derived key and use it to encrypt the users master key. The answers will not be stored in the database, just the key derived from them. The questions would be more opinion based than personal or factual.
This will mean there are two encrypted versions of the “master key”.

These questions would be added to the existing password reset form and the answers used to recreate the derived key and decrypt the master key. This would mean that the original master key can then be encrypted using the new password.

I have read many posts on how security questions should not be used to reset passwords but in this case it seems like an additional layer of security.

Does anyone see any potential problems with this approach or have any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Actually the security question becomes a second password then, and a weaker one probably. If the security question was equally safe as the password, users would forget it as well... So this is surely not an additional layer of security, it decreases security. On the other hand you are right, one cannot have both, a secure encryption based on the user password and a recovery function.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Its an extra level on the front end in that the security questions would have to be answered as well as a correct token provided.

Comment: For an _online_ attack it would be an advantage, though it weakens security for an _offline_ attack, when the data is already stolen (e.g. SQL-injection).

Comment: Probably there must be more than 1 questions and the second password to be calculated based on the combination of the answers.

Comment: @iakovosGurulian - Yes, I was thinking of 3 questions. One issue is that I have to allow for slight variations in the answers. I.e, convert all chars to uppercase and remove punctuation.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - how so? The result of the answers will be salted and hashed, as with the password and as it will be a combination of words / phrases would possibly result in a stronger password?

Comment: @Gavin, martinstoeckli is right since the answers to the questions might be easy to guess. But again, as was mentioned earlier, it is not easy to have everything. One more thing to consider is that users often type random things as answers (that they do not remember afterwards), so that it is not easy for someone to guess them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear who you are trying to protect the data from (your organisation or potential intruders), but I would presume that intruders is your main concern, since your organisation has access to the code of the application and therefore can view the passwords that the user is inputting (unless encryption/decryption takes place on the client side).

I would not encrypt the data using the passwords of the users. Instead, I would generate random key(s) for each user, store them on a separate server, and retrieve them once the user authenticates successfully. That separate server would have to be inaccessible from the outside world.

Note that user authentication should also take place on the second server as well. Do not return the keys without prior user authentication, in case the first server gets compromised. You can additionally encrypt these keys using the user passwords and on a different column, using a master key that you are holding in case someone forgets their passwords.

This way you will get stronger passwords as well, than what the average user is going to use.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to highlight who the data is to be protected from. Unfortunately, we don't have the resources to do this as we are using a 3rd party for hosting. I have also looked at the possibility of using 3rd party key managers.

Comment: I see. I do not like the approach of questions/answers, since they are often easily predictable, and an attacker might guess them without even compromising the server. Once that happens you will be unable to restore the data, if the attacker alters these answers and the password, so the original user would have lost all their data completely.

Comment: Fair point but to do that the password reset email / token system would have to be comprimised in the first place. The security questions are purely a way to decrypt the original master key to allow it to be encrypted with the new password.

Comment: OK I see, so these should be accessible only after the user receives an email. This should be good enough I think then, however I would still encrypt the sensitive data (using public key crypto so that the decryption key is not maintained in the server). In case a user does not remember the answers to the questions, but are still capable of somehow proving their identity to you, you will have the ability to manually recover the account then. One final thought is that you should ensure the integrity of the encrypted data to prevent data loss.

Comment: Thanks. Good point about encrypting the key with a public key also. I will have 3 encrypted versions of the master key and then and a private key on a local machine just in case.